# Refresh OAuth token using Reactivecocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

So what I'm trying to do is this.

- Make a HTTP request including a header which specifies the authorization token.
- If the response is a 401 Unauthorized I wish to use my refresh token to obtain a new access token and a new refresh token.
- When I have the new token pair I wish to retry the failed request using the new tokens.

I got this working by looking at [this](http://codeblog.shape.dk/blog/2013/12/02/transparent-oauth-token-refresh-using-reactivecocoa/) article. They solve it like this.

```
    - (RACSignal *)doRequestAndRefreshTokenIfNecessary:(RACSignal *)requestSignal {
return [requestSignal catch:^(NSError *error) {
    // Catch the error, refresh the token, and then do the request again.
    BOOL hasRefreshToken = [UserManager sharedInstance].refreshToken != nil;
    BOOL httpCode401AccessDenied = error.code == -1011;
    if (httpCode401AccessDenied && hasRefreshToken) {
        return [[[self refreshToken] ignoreValues] concat:requestSignal];
    }
    return requestSignal;
}];
}
```

But here's the catch. If I fire multiple requests with an expired access token I sometimes end up with a race condition where there are multiple refreshes.

So I thought that I could save the refresh signal as an instance variable and just "chain" all subsequent failed requests to that. But the result is that the refresh signal is done multiple times.

```
- (RACSignal *) refreshToken {
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"client_id": [Config clientId],
                         @"client_secret": [Config clientSecret],
                         @"grant_type": @"refresh",
                         @"refresh_token": [[Tokens sharedTokens] refreshToken]
                         };

if (self.activeRefreshSignal == nil) {
    @weakify(self)
    self.activeRefreshSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        @strongify(self)
        [[RestAPI sharedClient] POST:@"/oauth/token"
                                 parameters:params
                                    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
                                        [self extractTokensFromResponseObject:responseObject];
                                        [subscriber sendNext:nil];
                                        [subscriber sendCompleted];
                                        self.activeRefreshSignal = nil;
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        [[Tokens sharedTokens] clearTokens];
                                        [subscriber sendError:error];
                                        self.activeRefreshSignal = nil;
                                    }];
        return nil;
    }];
}

return self.activeRefreshSignal;
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid the race condition and only do one refresh?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Andreas?